# Imgur API: corrective action when x-post-rate-limit-reset is -1?

Tags: api, imgur

I see these response headers when I try to upload an image using the Imgur API:

```
x-post-rate-limit-limit: 1250
x-post-rate-limit-remaining: 0
x-post-rate-limit-reset: -1
```

[The docs](https://api.imgur.com/#limits) describe x-post-rate-limit-reset like this:

> X-Post-Rate-Limit-Limit:  Total POST credits that are allocated.
>
> X-Post-Rate-Limit-Remaining:  Total POST credits available.
>
> X-Post-Rate-Limit-Reset:  Time in seconds until your POST ratelimit is reset

What does X-Post-Rate-Limit-Reset = -1 mean in this context, and what corrective action can I take to restore my credits?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. To add some context: I've had a program that's been posting comments, and it's been running fine for 4-5 months. Then I suddenly ran into the rate limit a couple of weeks ago, so I dialed down the frequency and hoped it would start working next month. But instead I get the x-post-rate-limit-reset: -1 response header. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I never did.  I gave up and stopped using imgur for that application.